# Shopify Dynamic Page Titles & Descriptions

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

would love some pointers if any SHOPIFY tech heads know how to solve this

BACKGROUND:

We're setting up a shoe store using the shopify platform with a structure that divides collections primarily into gender, style, brand and this is done via tags. So for example you may have a shoe that has tags with Womens, Birkenstock, Sandals.

A typical URL maybe = /collections/womens/birkenstock/sandals.

THE CHALLENGE:

Now my CHALLENGE is in this example the page title and page description is based on the leading collection in the URL, that being 'women'.  Women in this instance does not best description to the user or search engines what this URL is about.

THE OUTCOMES NEEDED:

Is there a way you can create like dynamic page title & description in shopify from using a combination of {{ Collection }} {{ current_tags }}

/collections/womens/ = This would have a page name of womens-shoes

/collections/womens/birkenstock  = This would have a page name of Womens Birkenstocks

/collections/womens/birkenstock/sandals = This would have a page name of Womens Birkenstocks Sandals

Each would aslo have thier own unique page description and not base it on the leading collection of just 'women'.  Hope that makes sense.

I know I can create a collection of say womens-birkenstock or womens-birkenstock-sandals which would give me the result but for a number of reasons I really can't go down that path

Look forward to seeing if anyone knows how this works or even better an example of a SHOPIFY shop who has done this

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do pretty much exactly what you describe.

```
<title>{% case template %}
{% when 'collection'%}{{collection.title}} {{current_tags | join: " "}}
{% else %}{{page_title}}
{% endcase %}<title>
```

The difference is handling plurals since your example you would have a tag "Birkenstock" but want the title to contain "Birkenstocks"

You could use the same value for title and heading by capturing the derived value:

```
{% capture my_title %}{% case template %}
    {% when 'collection'%}{{collection.title}} {{current_tags | join: " "}}
    {% else %}{{page_title}}
    {% endcase %}{% endcapture %}
```

and then

```
<title>{{ my_title}}</title>
...

<h1>{{ my_title}}</h1>
```

Your problem here is actually more of how are you going to assemble these sets? If you are looking for an SEO effect you will need to have the multi-tag links associated with each collection wired into your theme so that the links (e.g. /collections/womens/birkenstock+sandal) are available from liquid rather than client side. This can get a little complicated because you also need to account for changing product setups and new tags so a simple setup is going to tend to end up with links to empty pages.

Comment: `/collections/womens/birkenstock/sandals` is that possible?

Comment: well the url in that case would be more like `/collections/womens/birkenstock+sandals` The plus sign (or %20) is used to join multiple tags.